# Limiting the Amount of Tags for Acts as Taggable On

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, tags, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am wondering how to limit the amount of tags, the tag_cloud function returns for this plugin. http://github.com/collectiveidea/acts-as-taggable-on

Also, I would like to know how to order it so that it orders the tags by the highest count. So the most popular are at the top.

I tried to do @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags, :limit => 5) but that did not work.

Controller:

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  def tag_cloud
     @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags)
  end
end
```

View:

```
 <% tag_cloud @tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4) do |tag, css_class| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class %>
 <% end %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest plugin version from github. It does work there, and it did not work in some earlier versions.

Then top 5 by the highest count will be:

```
@tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags, :limit => 5, :order => "count desc")
```

Comment: thanks voyta, i had to get collective idea's latest plugin for it to work. It seems mbleigh's version did not work with these commands.